# Vertical separators not displaying properly

Tags: tkinter, ttk

It might be hard to see in the paste but the second vertical separator is very small.

I have gotten horizontal separators to work and stretch as much as I want, but vertical do not seem to work.

Also, is it possible to cross vertical and horizontal separators so you can make a visible grid?

[image]

```
import tkinter as TK
from tkinter import ttk
import time

class GUI( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.root = TK.Tk()
        self.root.title( "test" )

        self.paddingFrame = TK.Frame( self.root )
        self.paddingFrame.config(pady="5")
        self.paddingFrame.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=TK.N)

        self.containFrame = TK.Frame( self.root )
        self.containFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=TK.W+TK.E, 
                               pady="5")

        self._horizontal_separators = []
        self._vertical_separators = []
        self._create_separators()

        self._update_button = TK.Button(
            self.containFrame, 
            text="Update",
            command = self.update_labels )
        self._update_button.configure(
            width="6", 
            padx="20", 
            pady="10" )
        self._update_button.grid(
            row=9, 
            column=0, 
            sticky=TK.E+TK.S )

    def _create_horizontal_separators( self ):
        for row in [ 1, 3 ]:
            sep = ttk.Separator( self.containFrame, 
                                 orient=TK.HORIZONTAL )
            sep.grid( row=row, columnspan=9, sticky="ew" )
            self._horizontal_separators.append( sep )

    def _create_vertical_separators( self ):
        for col in [ 2,3 ]:
            sep = ttk.Separator( self.containFrame, 
                                 orient=TK.VERTICAL )
            sep.grid( rowspan=10, column=col, sticky="sn")
            self._vertical_separators.append( sep )

    def _create_separators( self ):
        #self._create_horizontal_separators()
        self._create_vertical_separators()

    def update_labels(self):
        pass

    def start( self ):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    gui = GUI()
    gui.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code that is posted is that all but one row has a significant height. I'm seeing a vertical separator for that one row, as I would expect.

As for creating a visible grid, that's a duplicate of an existing question: [Show grid layout cells in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28025666/7432). The simplest solution is to give your background frame a solid color such as black, and the using padding between the rows and columns so that the background shows through.

Comment: TY, but is it possible to create a grid with separators or vertical and horizontal separators cannot cross each other?

Comment: @SoftWare: separators can cross each other if you use `place`, but that would require a fair amount of work for very little gain.